# ARM TrustZone, Hypervisor: Hypervisor functionality WITHOUT Virtualization Extensions

Tags: arm, virtualization, hypervisor, trustzone

I have found some interesting information regarding CPU virtualization for ARM and I'm wondering if you guys could help me understand more about it.

Basically, folks at some company called [***SierraWare***](http://www.sierraware.com/) have developed an ARM secure-mode OS called ***[SierraTEE](http://www.sierraware.com/open-source-ARM-TrustZone.html)*** that (they say) **virtualizes a guest OS like Linux/Android running in non-secure mode**, needing only the **Security Extensions**. A piece of information from one of their presentation documents has caught my attention, specifically at **page 19** of this PDF http://www.sierraware.com/sierraware_tee_hypervisor_overview.pdf they state:

> Integrity checks for Rootkits and Kernel Hacks:
>
> - **Monitor Syscall interrupt and interrupt handler**. This will ensure that core syscalls are not tampered with.

By "*Syscall interrupt*" I understand **SVC (=old SWI)** instruction executions (correct me if I'm wrong), but by "*monitoring*" I'm not really sure because it could be **real-time monitoring**, **from-time-to-time monitoring** or **on certain-events monitoring**. In my mind they could monitor the **SVC handler** to prevent tampering-with by either:

1. Inspect SVC handler **from time to time** (timer interrupt for instance, since IRQs and FIQs can be routed to monitor mode) - PatchGuard-like approach, doesn't seem very useful to me
2. Inspect SVC handler on **SVC instruction execution** (=*certain-events monitoring*)
3. Trap **SVC handlers** memory region write-access (=*real-time monitoring*)

Regarding **approach 2**: would it be possible to **trap non-secure SVC instruction executions** from secure-mode?

Regarding **approach 3**: would it be possible to hook non-secure memory-region writes ***by using only the Security Extensions***?

Thanks very much in advance

Comment: If you want a hypervisor, get a hypervisor.  TrustZone would protect the *secure OS*, and provides no protection for the *normal OS*.  Normally, a hypervisor must provide a *virtual mmu* to the hosted OS.  *TrustZone* provides two physical MMU tables.  Otherwise, SierraTEE has nothing to do with *TrustZone*.  Protection should be done with a **bus switch** to prevent over-writes.  Whatever the code is doing, it doesn't protect against an over-write of the checker in the *secure mode*.  From *secure mode*, you may inspect the *normal* (Android OS) and see if it is tampered.

Comment: *1.* is possible.  *2.* is impossible (without patching code or para-virtualization).  *3.* is also not possible without modifying Linux (para-virtualization).  All approaches assume some knowledge of the hosted OS (Linux/Android).  For instance, you can not run *FIQ* code such is used on some Linux IMX devices.  Without *secure boot*, anyone may over ride the checker.

Answer (score 0):

"Monitor" here may refer to the *Monitor mode*, the new mode added by the Security Extensions.

I'm not very familiar with the Security Extensions but I imagine it should be possible to mark specific memory regions as secure so any access to them will result in a Monitor mode trap, which can then handle the access and resume the non-secure code execution.

However, I just found this notice in the ARM ARM (B1.8.7 Summaries of asynchronous exception behavior):

> In an implementation that includes the Security Extensions but does
>   not include the Virtualization Extensions, the following
>   configurations permit the Non-secure state to deny service to the
>   Secure state. Therefore, ARM recommends that, wherever possible, these
>   configurations are not used:
>
> - Setting SCR.IRQ to 1. With this configuration, Non-secure PL1 software can set CPSR.I to 1, denying the required routing of IRQs to
>     Monitor mode.
> - Setting SCR.FW to 1 when SCR.FIQ is set to 1. With this configuration, Non-secure PL1 software can set CPSR.F to 1, denying
>     the required routing of FIQs to Monitor mode.
>
> The changes introduced by the Virtualization Extensions remove these
>   possible denials of service.

So it would seem it's not possible to achieve perfect virtualization with just Security Extensions.

Comment: I am pretty sure they mean *monitor* as in *to look at*, and not anything to do with the *monitor mode*.  But really, it is anybodies guess.  White papers are usually a technical *sales pitch*.  It is possible to provide something resembling virtualization with the *security extensions*, but it takes a lot more to create a secure system.  Marking the memory regions is usually done with something outside *ARM TrustZone*; Ie, the **bus switch** (connecting bus masters and slaves).